# Why is python OpenCV complaining about image not being single-channel 8bit?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm try to run the following code in python to detect lines in an image, but I'm getting an error complaining that the image is not an 8bit single channel image.

```
img = cv2.imread("source.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor (img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gb_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((ks, ks),sig,th,lm,0,0,cv2.CV_32F)
img_filtered = cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_32F, gb_kernel.transpose())
retval, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_filtered, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
print thresh.shape
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh, 1, np.pi/180, 200, 800, 0)
```

python output:

```
(1440, 993)
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The source image must be 8-bit, single-channel) in cvHoughLines2, file /Users/ericchaves/Projects/opencv-env/opencv-2.4.7/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp, line 712
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect-lines.py", line 22, in <module>
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh, 1, np.pi/180, 200, 800, 0)
cv2.error: /Users/ericchaves/Projects/opencv-env/opencv-2.4.7/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:712: error: (-5) The source image must be 8-bit, single-channel in function cvHoughLines2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Image should be grayscale and of type np.uint8. So convert it into np.uint8. Your image may be np.float32. You can check it by ``print thresh.dtype``

Comment: I needed `np.uint8` and not `np.int8` -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should pass `CV_8U` instead since the image is grayscale:

```
img_filtered = cv2.filter2D(gray, cv2.CV_8U, gb_kernel.transpose())
```

Answer (score 1):

you gave cv2.CV_32F for ddepth in [cv.filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#cv2.filter2D) so img_filtered is probably float